Real numbers equipped with the metric $d(x,y)=\arctan|x-y|$ is a complete metric space.
I have to show that, real numbers equipped with the metric $d(x,y)=\arctan|x-y|$ is a complete metric space.
The proof I am reading said that the function vanishes at $t = x-y = 0$, positive at $t>0$ and grows monotonously, therefore we only need to show the triangle inequality, i.e.:
$$\arctan(x-z) < \arctan(x-y) + \arctan(y-z)$$
This is the part which I don't understand, and even if this is correct, I don't know how to process further in the proof
Can you help me clarify this? Thank you.

Note that $d(x,y)=0$ iff $\arctan|x-y|=0$ iff $|x-y|=0$. Symmetry is obvious. So, to show that $d$ is a metric, it is enough to show that the triangle inequality works.
For completeness, note that for $0<\varepsilon<\frac{\pi}{2}$,
$$d(x,y)<\varepsilon\implies|x-y|<\tan\varepsilon$$
And for any $\varepsilon^\prime>0$,
$$|x-y|<\varepsilon^\prime\implies d(x,y)<\arctan\varepsilon^\prime$$
(Here, we used monotonicity of $\arctan$.)
Now, if $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy w.r.t. $d$, can you show that it is Cauchy w.r.t. the usual metric? Also, show that if it converges in the usual metric, then it converges in the $d$ metric.

Elaborating on the last few statements, to show that the given space is complete, we want to show that any Cauchy sequence converges.  Take a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$, i.e., for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that $d(x_n,x_m)<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\ge N$. Show that this implies that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N^\prime$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\ge N^\prime$. Then, $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$ with the Euclidean metric. This space is complete, so it converges to $x$. Now, go back in a similar fashion.
Hope this helps. :)

Can you please clarify, what is Cauchy with usual metric?

@kai1221: ${x_n}$ is Cauchy with the usual metric means that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$ for all $n,m\geq N$.

I am still a little bit confused. Could you write out the whole proof? I don't understand how, showing if {xn} is Cauchy w.r.t. d, then it is Cauchy w.r.t. the usual metric can prove that this metric space is complete

@kai1221  "a metric space M is called complete (or a Cauchy space) if every Cauchy sequence of points in M has a limit that is also in M." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space Perhaps you are working from a different definition of "complete"?

Yeah, no, I am working on this definition(The one on Wikipedia). Thank you for clarifying
